# Handsome tips (if this can be used)

Tags: collocations

My question is, do you use:

> The regular customer in a restaurant had given the waiter a **handsome tip** before he left.

Does the bold-letters collocate well?. (Handsome tip=big tip am I right)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please [edit] your post to [provide adequate detail](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/). A generous gratuity can be a handsome tip; the suggestion to keep your back rigid when swinging your driver, less so.

Comment: **Handsome** can also refer to behaviour, as in the phrase "Handsome is as handsome does."

Comment: You are right about the meaning, but you ask about the usage. I'd say that it's acceptable, although some might think it sounds a little bit old-fashioned. It's not common, but "uncommon" is not the same as "too awkward to use."

Comment: @J.R- what do you mean old-fashioned, is this originated from U.S.A? (Coz it's my first time that I've heard such 'handsome tip') do you have any other alternative and better way of saying it, please do give me one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handsome, in this context, means noticeably larger than normal, but not  necessarily exceptionally so. It could merely in the high end of the normal range.

In the US, a general rule is to tip 20% at restaurants (I have seen some restaurants print 18%, 20%, and 22% amounts on the bottom of a bill). Let us assume a $40 bill. The normal tip would therefore be $8. $10-12 would generally be seen as generous or handsome. (Although $10 may be easier due to the denominations of US currency).